# Vba: Can not establish an object as a range using ActiveWorkbook command, throws error 91

Tags: vba, with-statement

I'm trying to define a variable called dtecell as a range to do handle it in a more easy way. Simplifying, I have the following code:

```
Sub foo()


Dim dtecell As Range
Dim dte As Date
Dim twbook As Workbook
Dim dtwsheet As Worksheet

Set twbook = ActiveWorkbook
Set dtwsheet = twbook.Worksheets("BT_dd_mm_aaaa")

dtecell = dtwsheet.Range("H9")
dte = dtcell.Value
```

When it arrives to the line in which code defines `dtcell` it throws the error:

> VBA ACCESS error 91 object variable or with block variable not set

I dont't know why it throws that error. With is when you want to keep constant an object in order to not repeat it when applying methods over it, but here it has not sense.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Range is an object, use `Set dtecell = dtwsheet.Range("H9")`.

Comment: Also your last line uses `dtcell.Value`.  It should be `dtecell.value`

Comment: A typo. This would have been easier for you to catch if you put **`Option Explicit`** at the top of [every] module [always], as it will bring your attention to undeclared or mis-used variables, objects, properties, etc.